# Why doesn't an Image show up when I add it to a Document using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext, asp.net-2.0

Contextt: I am opening an existing, interactive PDF form containing AcroForm fields. I tried to add an image to a rectangle field in the PDF form like this:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("includes");
string newFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Tmp") + "/completed_gray" +".pdf";
string imagepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Tmp");
Document doc = new Document();
try {
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Open));
    doc.Open();
    iTextSharp.text.Image gif = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/CUstomRep_Eng_Col_1_V1.png");
    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = pdfStamper.AcroFields.GetFieldPositions("img_1_space")[0].position;
    gif.ScaleAbsolute(rect.Width, rect.Height);
    gif.SetAbsolutePosition(rect.Left, rect.Bottom);  
    doc.Add(gif);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    //Log error;
}
finally {
    doc.Close();
}
```

The image doesn't show up in the resulting PDF.

Comment: Please read about some formatting issues and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: What i syour question - are you seeing an error?  What is the error message?

Comment: Moreover: you say you're filling out an existing PDF and you're using the Document and the PdfWriter class? Clearly you didn't read the documentation, otherwise, you'd use PdfStamper!

Comment: What makes you think rect is located somewhere on an A4 page? Maybe the original document has completely different dimensions? I vote to close this question; this is not a real question.

Comment: @bruno, please give me some sample code that I can try.there is a AcroForm field(img_1_space) in the PDF. i want to add a wmf file(top left 1,1)bottom right 228,669 to this field. the field having the same co-ordinates.

Comment: You aren't giving sufficient information for anyone to do your work in your place. What type of field is img_1_space? Is it a button field? Is it a text field? You're not telling us, so we can't answer you. What is this top left and bottom right about? That's not how PDF works, you need lower-left and upper-right coordinates. BTW how do you know those coordinates if you don't know the position of the field? Your question is inconsistent and should be closed for that reason. It's not in a good Q&A form.

Comment: i have a blank editable pdf form with AcroForm fields.i can set some values to these fields with pdfFormFields.SetField command.one of the field should be set with an image.the position of the field and co-ordinates of the image should be same, because the image is extracted from the same pdf form same place.the x and y corners of the image as -the lower left(2,667)upper right(229,1)

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a document using the "5 steps to create a PDF document" as documented in my books.

1. create a Document object.
2. create a PdfWriter instance.
3. open the document.
4. add content to the document.
5. close the document.

This contradicts with what you actually want to do: I want to add an Image in a placeholder defined by an AcroForm field.

Why are you saying you want one thing, and doing something else? Beats me. Probably because you didn't want to read the documentation.

You need something like this:

1. Create a PdfReader instance.
2. Create a PdfStamper instance.
3. Ask the stamper for information about the fields.
4. Add content to a page using the stamper instance.
5. Close the stamper.

In answer to your question: *why doesn't my image show up in my document?*

Support the coordinates of the field in the existing document are lower-left corner x = 600, y = 600 and upper-right corner x = 700, y = 700, then you are adding the image outside the visible area of the page you're creating. When you use `new Document();`, you're creating a document where the lower-left corner is x = 0, y = 0 and the upper-right corner is x = 595, y = 842.

In that case, you're adding the image to the document, but it's not visible because you've added it outside the rectangle that defines the page.

Comment: thank you very much, as you referred I tried tio use the following code

Comment: PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
  PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
  AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
    iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(pathh + "/ADE_RepBtn_Nor.png");

Comment: iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = pdfStamper.AcroFields.GetFieldPositions("img_1_space")[0].position;
//Scale it      
 img.ScaleAbsolute(rect.Width, rect.Height);
                             //Position it
                             img.SetAbsolutePosition(rect.Left, rect.Bottom);
                    //          //Add it to page 1 of the document
                             pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1).AddImage(img);
                             stamper.Close();